# Racket recursive function for returning the sum of a list of squared numbers

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to Racket, and I am trying to write a recursive function that takes a number `n` and returns the sum of the squares of the first `n` integers. For example, `(this-function 3)` returns 14 because 14 is 9 + 4 + 1 + 0.

I tried creating two separate functions, one that squares each number and returns a list of the squared numbers, and a second that sums up the list. The function the squares each number is:

```
(define (squared my-list)
  (cond [(empty? my-list) empty]
        [(zero? my-list) 0] 
        [else (cons (expt  my-list 2)
                    (cons (squared   (sub1 my-list)) empty))]))
```

which if I run `(squared 3)` returns `(cons 9 (cons (cons 4 (cons (cons 1 (cons 0 empty)) empty)) empty))`.

When I run the second function (the sum function):

```
(define (sum numbers)
  (cond
    [(empty? numbers) 0]
    [else (+ (first numbers) (sum (rest numbers)))]))
```

and run `(sum (squared 3))` I get an error message because `(squared 3)` returns an extra "cons" in the list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Are you permitted to use functions like `foldl` and `map`?

Comment: It is. I've come this far, but still suck because of the extra cons. And no we haven't learned foldl and map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in `squared` is a little bit off. I'll explain the issues clause-by-clause.

```
[(empty? my-list) empty]
```

This doesn't make any sense since `my-list` will never even be a list. In fact, `my-list` is poorly named. The parameter `squared` takes is a *number*, not a list. This clause can be completely removed.

```
[(zero? my-list) 0]
```

This is what the *actual* terminating case should be, but it shouldn't return `0`. Remember, `squared` has to return a *list*, not a number. *This* case should return `empty`.

```
[else (cons (expt my-list 2)
            (cons (squared (sub1 my-list)) empty))]))
```

Finally, this clause is far too complicated. You have the right idea—to `cons` the new number onto the rest of the list—but you're cons'ing too many times. Remember, the result of `(squared (sub1 my-list))` is itself a list, and the second argument of `cons` is the rest of the list. You don't need the extra cons—you can just eliminate it completely.

Combining these changes, you get this, which does what you want:

```
(define (squared my-list)
  (if (zero? my-list) empty
      (cons (expt my-list 2)
            (squared (sub1 my-list)))))
```

(I also replaced `cond` with `if` since `cond` is no longer necessary.)

---

That said, this code is not very Racket-y. You had a good idea to break up your function into two functions—in functional programming, functions should really only ever do *one* thing—but you can break this up further! Specifically, you can leverage Racket's built-in higher-order functions to make this type of thing extremely easy.

You can replace your entire `squared` function by appropriately combining [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) and [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29). For example, the following creates a list of the squares from 0–3.

```
(map (curryr expt 2) (range 4))
```

(You need to call `(range 4)` because the list generated by [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29) goes from 0 to n-1.)

Next, you can easily sum a list using [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29). To sum the above list, you'd do something like this:

```
(apply + (map (curryr expt 2) (range 4)))
```

That gives you the appropriate result of `14`. Obviously, you could encapsulate this in its own function for clarity, but it's a lot clearer what the above code is doing once you learn Racket's functional constructs.

(However, I'm not sure if you're allowed to use those, since your question looks a lot like homework. Just noted for future reference and completeness.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. And explaining it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution is to use the closed form:

```
(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (* 1/6 n (+ n 1) (+ n n 1)))
```

Credit: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_i%3D1%5En+i%5E2)

Answer (score 0):

one function for providing a list of squares and one function for summing up the list is not necessary. 
This will do the trick, and is recursive as required.

```
(define (my-sq n)
(cond [(zero? n) 0]
      [else
       (+ (* n n) (my-sq (- n 1)))]))

(my-sq 3) -> 14
```